# Math For Pong Game

Tags: java, math

Lets say I have an angle... what would be a reasonable way to go about finding the next point of where the ball would be?

Variables: bSpeed, bAngle, Ball.x, Ball.y

You knwon when you do c^2 = a^2 + b^2... is there a way you could find how long c^2 could be and actually "draw" it out and then use speed to go only part of that... with that find a^2 and b^2 so you can actually have a x and a y to draw the ball...

Thanks ahead of time! (BTW, I don't need code... just reasoning and wisdom)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your 4 variables are effectively a vector - where the vector is a measure of both direction and magnitude/velocity (i.e. what you've represented as bSpeed and bAngle).  Using this representation means that Ball.x and Ball.y simply become the horizontal and vertical components of the vector.

Given a vector called v1 we can calculate the movement in the x and y axis as follows...

```
xVelocityOfBall = v1.magnitude * cos(v1.angle);
yVelocityOfBall = v1.magnitude * sin(v1.angle);
```

GPWiki (Games Programming Wiki) is a great resource for anything maths/physics for games development.  Here's a handy link to their [vector page](http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/Vector)

Answer (score 2):

```
delta_x = speed*cos(angle)
delta_y = speed*sin(angle)
new_x = x+delta_x
new_y = y+delta_y
```

and then you need just change speed and angle of ball in the case of wall strike)

Answer (score 0):

Open up your textbooks on Sin, Cos and Tan since you're using bAngle. Specifically you'll probably be looking Sin for the vertical motion and Cos for the horizontal motion. Depending on where you've defined degree 0 to face.

Also, you could consider caching the horizontal and vertical speeds since Sin and Cos are expensive

Answer (score 0):

You probably will need to consider the physics of the movement that the pong player is moving also. For example, if a player's paddle is speeding to the left as it contacts the ball, the ball will need to speed up wrt to the left direction. This represents transfer of momentum in physics. The general system of equations in the x and y directions will always be:

1. mass*velocity (in x) = the sum of the mass*velocity of all objects in x
2. mass*velocity (in y) = the sum of the mass*velocity of all objects in y

generally speaking sine you always have the speed of the ball in x and y all you need to do is determine the masses of both the ball and the paddles (i suppose that's up to you but I suggest making them the same for ease of calculation).

In terms of solving for the angle, it's very simple, you would just make sure the reflection is equal. If the ball is approaching a paddle (or wall) from a 60 degree incident, then the bounce should also be at a 60 degree incident.

Answer (score 0):

First, convert the angle to a vector using the `sin` and `cos` functions.  This tells you the relative x-speed and y-speed of the ball.  Then, to find out how far the ball actually went, multiply these numbers by the ball's speed and time-of-flight.  Finally, add to the ball's starting position.  This gives you the ball's ending position.

In a pong game, the ball may hit an object, in which case you need to correct for the change in velocity.